# Disable SPC in spacemacs

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, edebug

In edebug, if I press `SPC` it should jump to the next stop point. But in spacemacs, if I press `SPC`, a tips window will appear. So how to disable `SPC` so that I can use edebug space command?

Comment: Are you aware that the [Emacs Lisp Layer](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/emacs-lisp/README.html#debugging), defines Spacemacs specific keybindings? Personally, I find them to be well-chosen. It adds come handy evaluation keybindings also...

Comment: @dalanicolai Thank you! `s` works.